# Numbers to binary and back

Tags: functions, homework, binary

I am struggling on how to create a function that converts a number into binary and then back. I know there is a built-in function about this `BaseForm[]` but I am trying not to use it.
I started thinking about using the `RealDigits[]` but I don't really know where to go from here. I will keep trying and post any code I do.
If anyone can help me with this I would be really grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Out of curiosity, why would you not want to use the built-in functions?

Comment: Thanks! I am a beginner in Mathematica and following a course. There is a exercise in which I am not allowed to use BaseForm[] sadly.

Comment: Homework questions are welcome, if you show your meaningful work so far and ask a specific question.

Comment: I usually use `IntegerDigits[]` and `FromDigits[]`, but if this is homework, then it probably asks you to calculate the digits not using the built-in functions. In this case, you will probably want `Mod[m,n]` (modulo operation, reminder) and `Floor[m/n]` (integer part after the division).

Answer (score 2):

Just to illustrate ways to do *you own* way:

Binarize integer:

```
binary[n_] := 
 Reverse@NestWhileList[
    QuotientRemainder[#[[1]], 2] &, {n}, # != {0, 0} &][[2 ;; -2, 2]]
```

This produces a list, e.g. `binary[23]` yields: {1, 0, 1, 1, 1}.

You can invert:

```
frombinary[n_] := 
With[{k = Length[n]}, n . PowerRange[2^(k 
- 1), 1, 1/2]]
```

If you want create output like `BaseForm`:

```
bf[n_] := Subscript[Row[binary[n]], 2]
```

You can invert this by accessing list, e.g.

```
bf2d[n_] := frombinary[(n[[1, 1]])]
```

where input is `Subscript[Row[...]]`,

The in-built functions are optimized. I present this to motivate "create your own" play.

**Update/Edit**

In response to comment:

```
binary[n_] := 
 Reverse@NestWhileList[
    QuotientRemainder[#[[1]], 2] &, {n}, # != {0, 0} &][[2 ;; -2, 2]]
binary[0] = {0};
dec[n_] := 
 NestWhileList[
   Reverse@MixedFractionParts[2 #[[1]]] &, {n}, # != {0, 
      0} &][[2 ;; -2, 2]]
anybin[n_] := 
 Module[{i = IntegerPart[n], f = FractionalPart[n]}, 
  Subscript[Row[Join[binary[i], {"."}, dec[f]]], 2]]
```

Comparing with BaseForm:

```
Table[{j, BaseForm[j, 2], 
   anybin[j]}, {j, {0.5, 1.25, 3.75, 1.2, 0.13}}] // 
 TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {None, {"n",  "BaseForm","anybin"}}] &
```

[image]

Noting: fractions such as 1/5 do not have binary finite representations.

e.g.

```
Sum[2^(-4 j + 1) + 2^(- 4 j), {j, 1, 3}] // N
Limit[Sum[2^(-4 j + 1) + 2^(- 4 j), {j, 1, x}], x -> Infinity]
```

They are recurring. This could truncated to show repeating sequence. I leave that to enthusiast.

Comment: It's a (+1) from me, but a relevant comment: the `binary[0.13]` does not work and this was pointed out by the author of the OP under my reply in the comments. Perhaps you'd like to update your answer

Comment: @bmf thank you. I apologize for not reading OP question well enough. As I wrote in answer  "Binarize integer". However, I take your point.

Comment: yes, of course I understand. And my comment was only meant to serve as hint for an improvement. I do find your answer very good indeed :)

Answer (score 1):

### **Edit: addressing the comment**

Updated code is:

```
test[xx_, digits_: 17] := If[xx >= 1,
    ToString@Row@Insert[#1, ".", #2 + 1] & @@ 
   RealDigits[xx, 2, digits], 
  ToString@Row@
    Join[{0}, 
     Insert[Join[
       ConstantArray[0, Abs[RealDigits[xx, 2, digits][[2]]]], 
       RealDigits[xx, 2, digits][[1]]], ".", 1]]]
```

Checks:

> [image: tests]

---

---

### **Original answer below:**

---

### **To binary**

---

```
tobinary[realnum_] := 
 ToString@Row@Insert[#1, ".", #2 + 1] & @@ RealDigits[#, 2] &[realnum]
```

And we have

```
Table[tobinary[ii], {ii, 0, 4, 1}]
```

> [image: b]

which can be compared with

```
Table[BaseForm[i, 2], {i, 0, 4}]
```

> [image: bb]

Works also for

```
tobinary[17.27]
```

> [image: rd]

---

### **From binary**

---

```
frombinary[mynumber_] := FromDigits[RealDigits[mynumber], 2]
```

Quick check:

```
frombinary[100]
```

> [image: fb]

And works also for

```
frombinary[10001.010001010001111010111000010100011110101110000101] // 
 N
```

> [image: rd2]

---

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way for it to work for lowers decimals? Because when I try using for example  0.23 it doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: @peter21 you might want to look at the edited version. The key was to understand the output of `RealDigits[0.21, 2, 11]`

Comment: @peter21 so, does the updated version work as you were expecting?

Comment: yep works perfectly thanks!

Comment: @peter21 thanks for letting me know :)